# Is there an r function for counting how many data points fit into certain categories?

Tags: r, variables, encoding, count, data-analysis

I am working on a data set involving the details from various fatal police shootings from Jan 2015 till now. The details involve race, presence of body camera, age and more.

[image]

from this data set, I would like to count how many situations involved a body camera (in the "body_camera" column it would read as "TRUE") and at the same time involved a black victim (which reads as "B"). Id also like to do the same with victims who were white "W".

If anyone could help with this it would be much appreciated, I'm struggling.

Comment: Please use `dput(head(mydf))` instead of a screenshot. Otherwise, you can use `dplyr::count(mydf, var1, var2)`

Comment: See the “table()” function

Comment: There is no column called `body_camera` in your submitted data picture.

Comment: oh wow I'm sorry, how do I attach the data?

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide data, I chose too use the `mtcars` dataset, which is built into r. Just like your dataset, each row represents an individual (in this case, different cars). And it also has variables with the same categorical properties as your "bodycam" and "ethnicity" variable.
Just that they are called "vs" (V-shaped engine), which is either 0 (= V-shaped) or 1 (= straight), and "cyl" (cylinders), which has the expressions 4, 6 and 8. For more detail, type `?mtcars`.

To count the frequency of something, there is the `table` function.

```
df <- mtcars
table(df$vs, df$cyl)
```

which yields these results:

```
> table(df$vs, df$cyl)
   
     4  6  8
  0  1  3 14
  1 10  4  0
```

Now to get the amount of cars that have a straight engine AND 4 cylinders, just read the table. The code equivalent to reading the table works by indexing:

```
> table(df$vs, df$cyl)[2,1]
[1] 10
```

Here is another approach. You can also translate the criteria (straight engine AND 4 cylinders) into code and specify a conditional statement using the & operator.

```
df$vs == 1 & df$cyl == 4
```

This yields a rather human unreadable TRUE and FALSE set.
To make this better, we can use `which`, which returns the rows at which the condition is true.

```
> which(df$vs == 1 & df$cyl == 4)
 [1]  3  8  9 18 19 20 21 26 28 32
```

Now we just have to count how many rows there are for which the condition is TRUE.
To count the overall number of items, there is `length`.
`table`does not get us anywhere for this counting task, as it would try to count the frequency of each item, and each row occurs exactly once.

```
> length(which(df$vs == 1 & df$cyl == 4))
[1] 10
```

This corresponds to what we can read from the table for a straight engine and 4 cylinders.

Hope this helps!